Sufficient condition for two finite abelian groups to be isomorphic.
I have two finite abelian groups and the number of elements in each with any given order is identical.  Does this imply the groups are isomorphic?

Does $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ suffice as a counterexample? They are non-isomorphic, and neither have elements with finite order.

@AlkaKadri   Yes you are correct.  However, I wanted to only consider finite groups.  I edited my question.  Thanks.

This question really is lacking sufficient context, so I am voting to close.

Any finite abelian group of order $n$ is isomorphic to a product of cyclic groups with prime power order (where the primes are the prime decomposition of $n$), so yes! See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2729266/isomorphisms-of-finite-abelian-groups

This has been asked before, see: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72944/two-finite-abelian-groups-with-the-same-number-of-elements-of-any-order-are-isom
It also appears in the form of a paper in some journal, but I don't recall the details now.

I have an abelian group with 1 element of order 1, 27 elements of order 2, 8 elements of order 3, 36 elements of order 4, and 24 elements of order 6.  How can I tell what group it is?

It does not exist.

@Anne Bauval.   Yes,  Thank you.
